# Parsing integers as fast as possible

Tags: c, optimization, integer

I'm trying to optimize parsing strings to uint64 values in C. At the moment I use a naive solution:

```
uint64_t parse(const char *source)
{
   uint64_t res = 0;
   while (source[0] >= '0' && source[0] <= '9') {
       res = res * 10 + (source[0] - '0');
       ++source;
   }
   return res;
}
```

However, this is not that fast. My first optimization was actually to replace `isdigit(c)` by a simple comparison (which is way faster due to the implementation of `isdigit`). Unfortunately, that was as well my last optimization.

There are some posts which describe some bit magic tricks, but they always seem to assume fix sized integers:
https://kholdstare.github.io/technical/2020/05/26/faster-integer-parsing.html

Are there any tricks to make integer parsing as well faster for the case that the integer has an unknown length?

Thanks

Comment: - and you are sure that this is the performance bottleneck?

Comment: I get the impression that you aren't compiling with optimizations enabled.

Comment: @user3386109: I'm compiling with `-Ofast -march=native` which should include all important optimizations.
@500-InternalServerError: Currently this is actually one of the most expensive parts of a very often executed code (the code takes ~40ns and this part is more than 10ns).

Comment: I don't think it warrants being a complete answer, but: use the fix-sized integer approach, having first obtained the length of your string and therefore knowing how many fix-sized items you can divide it into (plus perhaps one to three or seven extra characters to deal with).

Comment: perhaps a better question for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). But 10ns still too slow? Might need to go to FPGA land.

Comment: As an aside, it's strange to use `source[0]` with a constant index in this context.  If the pointer is changing, and you're always accessing its direct target, it's much more standard to use `*source`.  If the pointer didn't change, and you instead had an index `i`, then you'd use `source[i]`.

Comment: Your code returns the number. But, it does _not_ return the _updated_ `source` pointer variable. At a minimum, you may want to do what `strtol` does (it has a `char **` arg that is used to return the updated pointer value). You could look at the source code for `strtol`. If there's a faster algorithm, most libc impl will be using it.

Comment: Do you have control of the code generating the string? In that case, that's where you should attack.

Comment: But, using `isdigit` _may_ be faster than the range check, particularly if you also check for 0x00 (which you don't currently--but should). Using a separate `int`: `uint64_t parse(const char *source,char **ptr) { uint64_t res = 0;  while (1) { int chr = *source;  if (! isdigit((unsigned char) chr) break;  res = res * 10 + (chr - '0');  ++source; }  if (ptr != NULL) *ptr = (char *) source;  return res; }`

Comment: @KevinMeier I see. My comment was based on your statement that using comparisons is "way faster" than using `isdigit`. A while ago, I wrote similar code that converts 32-bit signed numbers (with overflow detection). For 11 character strings, e.g. `-1234567890`, it takes 13 nsec using comparisons, but only 11 nsec using `isdigit`. So `isdigit` is not slow if implemented and optimized properly. I was using -O3.

Comment: Optimization is most often situation-dependent. On what hardware are you running? What operating system? Where is the data coming from? Where is it going to? What are the cache characteristics? What else is competing for cache? Are most of the numbers just a few digits? Are there any patterns in the data that can be exploited? Can the parsing be multithreaded with other work? And so on.

Comment: To optimize your code probably you need to use some bitwise, and some compiler optimize-for-speed flags.

Comment: Tested manual unrolls and they perform slightly better than the OPs version.

Comment: You could simplify with while ((*source & 0xf0) == 0x30). The optimiser might already do something like this so it might not speed it up at all. Depends how clever it is. You could try SIMD for more speed if you can parse a number of strings at the same time.

Comment: @SimonGoater how can it help?

Comment: Hmm.. I thought having just one comparison it would be fewer operations, but now I'm not sure.

Comment: @SimonGoater `while ((*source & 0xf0) == 0x30)` allows any ASCII code from 0x30 to 0x3F, which includes the 10 digits and 6 non-digits.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks, yes I realised that after going to bed. You can still do it with one comparison though. See my posted answer.

Comment: @SimonGoater Yup, subtracting 48 as unsigned, and then comparing with 10 is exactly what `isdigit()` does when the loop is written as `while (isdigit(*source))`. So it just proves that if you're using a quality compiler, and you let the compiler does it's job, then you can write simple, easy to read code, and the compiler will optimize it for you.

Comment: @user3386109 At least `gcc` and `clang` will always call `__ctype_b_loc` if `isdigit(...)` is called. Even if the provided argument is a compile-time constant. This function call is followed by the evaluation of some flags in a table. Due to that it's quite expensive (compared to the naive comparison).

Comment: @KevinMeier [Here's the source that I wrote, and the assembly that clang produces.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qAwy.png) There's no call to any function. And you aren't going to beat that assembly code (except for the two instructions after the loop which have nothing to do with `isdigit`). So I don't know what you did when you tried `isdigit`, but you did something wrong, and that's all there is to it. Try it again, and check the assembly to make sure you got it right.

Comment: @user3386109 Okay, that's quite interesting. For small pieces of code I usually use godbolt to check the generated code: https://godbolt.org/z/nhjh3s3rG or https://godbolt.org/z/vnWzY64sc Here clang 15.0.0 clearly inserts the function call. I'm not sure why this is not consistent with your version (which I think is clearly the better version).

Comment: It's strange that the optimization is not universal. The trivial features it depends on (subtraction and unsigned comparison) *are* mandatory for all implementations, and guaranteed to work by the C standard. So I think you need to contact the team that maintains the compiler to see why that optimization isn't being used everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Tested three different implementations:

Manual unroll is slightly faster than the OP's loop version.

```
#define GET1(result, c) do {result *= 10; if((c) >= '0' && (c) <= '9')  
result += (c) - '0'; else return result;} while(0)
  

uint64_t parse2(const char *source)
{
    uint64_t result = 0;
    GET1(result, source[0 ]);
    GET1(result, source[1 ]);
    GET1(result, source[2 ]);
    GET1(result, source[3 ]);
    GET1(result, source[4 ]);
    GET1(result, source[5 ]);
    GET1(result, source[6 ]);
    GET1(result, source[7 ]);
    GET1(result, source[8 ]);
    GET1(result, source[9 ]);
    GET1(result, source[10]);
    GET1(result, source[11]);
    GET1(result, source[12]);
    GET1(result, source[13]);
    GET1(result, source[14]);
    GET1(result, source[15]);
    GET1(result, source[16]);
    GET1(result, source[17]);
    GET1(result, source[18]);
    GET1(result, source[19]);
    return result;
}


#define GET(result, c)          \
      result *= 10;switch(c)                            \
   {                                    \
        case '0' ... '9':               \
            result += (c) - '0';        \
            break;                      \
        case 0:                         \
        default:                        \
            return result;              \
   }                                    


uint64_t parse1(const char *source)
{
    uint64_t result = 0;
    GET(result, source[0 ]);
    GET(result, source[1 ]);
    GET(result, source[2 ]);
    GET(result, source[3 ]);
    GET(result, source[4 ]);
    GET(result, source[5 ]);
    GET(result, source[6 ]);
    GET(result, source[7 ]);
    GET(result, source[8 ]);
    GET(result, source[9 ]);
    GET(result, source[10]);
    GET(result, source[11]);
    GET(result, source[12]);
    GET(result, source[13]);
    GET(result, source[14]);
    GET(result, source[15]);
    GET(result, source[16]);
    GET(result, source[17]);
    GET(result, source[18]);
    GET(result, source[19]);
    return result;
}
```

Results (1000000000 iterations - 20char long number):

```
OPs parse: 14.26654600 seconds 
parse2   : 13.39631300 seconds 
parse1   : 12.98047100 seconds
```

Comment: I like your code, and I like the idea of using Macros.

Comment: The code currently has a small bug: The "multiply by 10" is done at the wrong place and due to that `parse1("123")` will return `1230`. However, fixing that is trivial and so far this is the fastest code:)

Comment: @KevinMeier performancewise it does not change anything

Comment: Yes that's true. Theoretically the code will be even slightly faster, because one multiplication less will be done.

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, you could cast `*source` to an `unsigned char`.  After subtracting '0' you only then need to perform one comparison.

You could also influence branch prediction with `[[likely]]` if that's available to you (*it doesn't have any effect in this case*)

If you were to know the string length in advance then fetching and processing more than one byte at a time would be possible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

uint64_t parse(const char *source) {
    uint64_t res = 0;
    while(true) {
        unsigned char digit = (unsigned char)(*source++ - '0');
        if (digit > 9) [[unlikely]] {
            break;
        }
        res = res * 10 + digit;
   }
   return res;
}

int main() {
    auto num = parse("1234567890");
    std::cout << num << "\n";    
    return 0;
}
```

Demo - https://godbolt.org/z/5q15P5611

Comment: Did you benchmark it? Does it change anything? The question is about the performance. It is staged C not C++

Comment: I'll need to test if the "unlikely" changes anything. At least the optimization with only using one comparison is already done by gcc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what appears to be a slight improvement on the OP's function. It doesn't need for source to be at least 20 bytes, unlike the unrolled versions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

// gcc intparse.c -o intparse.bin -O3

uint64_t parse(const char *source)
{
   uint64_t res = 0;
   while (source[0] >= '0' && source[0] <= '9') {
       res = res * 10 + (source[0] - '0');
       ++source;
   }
   return res;
}


uint64_t myparse(const unsigned char *source)
{
   uint64_t res = 0;
   unsigned char digit = *source - 48;
   while (digit < 10) {
       res = res * 10 + digit;
       ++source;
       digit = *source - 48;
   }
   return res;
}



uint64_t  get_cycles () {
  uint32_t lo,hi;
  asm  volatile("rdtsc":"=a"(lo),"=d"(hi));
  return  (( uint64_t)hi<<32 | lo);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char*needle_in_string;    
    uint64_t cycleno1, cycleno2, reslong;
    cycleno1 = get_cycles ();
    reslong = myparse(argv[1]);
    cycleno2 = get_cycles ();
    printf("%lu (%li cycles)\n", reslong, cycleno2 - cycleno1);
    cycleno1 = get_cycles ();
    reslong = parse(argv[1]);
    cycleno2 = get_cycles ();
    printf("%lu (%li cycles)\n", reslong, cycleno2 - cycleno1);
}
```

I got results...

```
1234567890123456789 (280 cycles)
1234567890123456789 (552 cycles)
```

and

```
55 (120 cycles)
55 (400 cycles)
```

Comment: `It doesn't need for source to be at least 20 bytes, unlike the unrolled versions.` I think you do not understand how the unrolled version works :)

Comment: One call does not show the performance

Comment: So far none of the versions are significantly faster than the naive approach. This version creates one less instruction in the loop body, but the speed difference does not seem to be that big. Still it's a small improvement:)

Comment: @0___________ My mistake. Didn't read it properly, sorry.